# no tests found with test runner JUnit 5 even after adding Junit Library

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, junit5

I wanted to test my classes in Java using JUnit 5, in Eclipse. all the files are in the same package. My test file is correct (syntax wise) and i get no errors from eclipse regarding the file itself. Only when i try to run the testfile, do i get the error: `No tests found with test runner JUnit 5`

I am really frustrated because i cannot seem to find the issue. i have included the JUnit-Library in my module path. I dont know if posting my code makes any sense, because i think it might be a different issue. Does anyone have any experience with this kind of error?

**edit**: here's a screenshot of my run configurations
[image]

Comment: What is in your Run configuration and are you sure you are not using any libs or functions or imports incompatible with JU5?

Comment: @Ecto what do you mean by "run configurations" ? How do i know if its not compatible? Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: You should post a detailed description of how to reproduce the issue, including code. The only thing anyone knows at the moment reading your question is that you are frustrated (is that something that one needs to know to answer the question?) because you think you did everything right by adding in an unknown way (yes, there are several ways to do this) a JUnit library of unknown version in an unknown Eclipse version and running it in an unknown way (yes, there are several ways to do this, too).

Comment: @sepæpa click on Run -> Run configurations... and describe which options are you using. Also a simplified piece of your code would be helpful.

Comment: i made a screenshot of my run configurations in the edit :)

Comment: It looks like, that you use "Junit4" Library imports, instead "Junit5" (jupiter) imports. Please check your imports

Comment: `@Before` is not compatible with JU5. Use `@BeforeEach` or `@BeforeAll`

Comment: @PaulFranke I am using the following imports:
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Objects;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

Comment: @sepæpa remove unused imports after you try getting rid of `@Before` and `@After`

Comment: @sepæpa .. use "import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;" instead " import org.junit.Test" and so on ("import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;", ...") . 
"junit.jupiter" librarys for Junit5

Comment: @PaulFranke Thanks for the tipp, i changed it. i also changed 
```import static org.junit.Assert.*; ``` 
to
```import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;```

Comment: i still get the same error though... :( 
in the code i get the error: ```the attribute expected is undefined for the annotation type Test```

Comment: And are you using some attributes for annotation Test?

Comment: Consider deleting your question until you have learned the differences between JUnit 4 and 5 (JUnit 5 is not backward compatible, hence the new error) and undelete the question not befor having a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Ecto 
```@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)``` is what im doing

Comment: remove that. JUnit 5 uses `Assertions.assertThrows`.

Comment: so instead it would look like this : ```@Test(Assertion.assertThrows = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class) ``` ?

Comment: no, just use `@Test` and into the body of the function add something like this: `Assertions.assertThrows(ExceptionName.class, () -> someObject.someFunction(args));`  Look at https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/expected-exception-example/ for more info.

Comment: @Ecto Thank you for your help. I was able to correctly apply the command in the following way ```assertThrows(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class, () -> myList.remove(3));```
however it seems that i still use wrong commands because i still get the original error of ```No tests found with test runner JUnit 5```:(

Comment: @sepæpa remove all testing related imports and add only those: `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;`
 let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: @Ecto first of all, thank you for your many responses :) 
i removed all imports and added the ones you told me to, still error. I was notified that the JUnit5 Library has to be included in the ```classpath```. I had it in the ```modulepath``` once i changed it to the ```classpath```and removed it from the ```modulepath``` the error disappeared...

Comment: @sepæpa great so everything works?

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if you added the Junit5 Library to your Java build path (Libraries).

[image: Eclipse Java Build Path Libraries]

If not, add the Library to your Java build path.

Comment: I have added the library before asking this question, i should have included this in the post. Thank you for your answer though :)

Comment: Should it be in the ```classpath```  or the ```modulepath``` ?

Comment: It should be in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

You can add Junit 5 libraries to your build path by right clicking on the project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Add library -> Junit -> Junit 5 -> Finish to run the test in your IDE.

Comment: I have added the library before asking this question, i should have included this in the post. Thank you for your answer though :)